# Save oracle objects in tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oop, plsql, oracle11g

I've read about OOP in Oracle. Did some practice on inserting objects into tables.
For example:

```
create or replace type person as object(
 id number,
 name varchar2(50),
 age number,
 constructor function person return self as result,
 constructor function person(id number, name varchar2, age number) return self as result,
 member procedure set_id(id in number),
 member function get_id return number,
 member procedure set_name(name in varchar2),
 member function get_name return varchar2,
 member procedure set_age(age in number),
 member function get_age return number,
 member function to_string return varchar2
)
```

Type body:

```
create or replace type body person as
 constructor function person return self as result is
  begin
    self := person();
    return;
  end;

 constructor function person(id in number, name in varchar2, age in number) return self as result is
  begin
    self.id := id;
    self.name := name;
    self.age := age;
    return;
  end;


 member procedure set_id(id in number) is
  begin
    self.id := id;
  end;

 member function get_id return number is
  begin 
    return self.id;
  end;

 member procedure set_name(name in varchar2) is
  begin
    self.name := name;
  end;

 member function get_name return varchar2 is
  begin
    return self.name;
  end;


member procedure set_age(age in number) is
 begin
   self.age := age;
 end;

member function get_age return number is
 begin
   return self.age;
 end;

member function to_string return varchar2 is
 begin
   return 'Person={id='||self.get_id||', name='||self.get_name||', age='||self.get_age||'}';
 end;

end;
```

Create some table:

```
create table test_objs(
 id number,
 person person
)
```

And some DML:

```
insert into test_objs(id, person) values(1, person(1, 'Test person', 25));

select * from test_objs;
```

The result is:

[image]

Looks great for me, and it is better to work with objects instead of couple of arguments in procedures/functions (imho). Oracle has good OOP (it will be super if they add encapsulation too). I create objects, save these objects in tables, create stored programs which work with objects and so on.. But I did not see anywhere people keeping data as objects or doing fully oop in db level. Do experts advise this way of db programming? What are the cons and pros of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not oracle behavior, PL/SQL developer helps you to understands information that you store in the table, for example when I use SQL*Plus, I can see:

```
SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> create type person as object (
  2    id number(10),
  3    name varchar2(20 char)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> drop table ttt;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table ttt (
  2    person person
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into ttt values (person(1, 'somename'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from ttt;

PERSON(ID, NAME)
-----------------------------------------------------
PERSON(1, 'somename')

SQL> select person.id from ttt;
select person.id from ttt
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "PERSON"."ID": invalid identifier
```

As you can see, SQL*Plus doesn't split the `person` column into several columns, it shows it as a whole object.

People doesn't use it, because:

- it's easier to manage relational model than object model.
- relational model is easier in constructing SQL queries. You don't need other functions to extract value.

Comment: But we can do something like: \n

`select treat(t.person as person).name p from ttt t`

People does not use objects in tables only because it is ugly in sqlplus* ? :) Not sure.

Comment: I didn't say that, I told him, that his conclusion is based on the tool he used, I showed him that SQL*Plus displays this data on its own way and there is not physical columns for person.id nor for person.name.

Comment: Yes, there are actually physical columns for person.id and person.name. But when you select them, you need to use a table alias as in "select t.person.id from ttt t;" This is documented. Creating object tables in Oracle does create relational tables "behind the scenes". The "trouble" is that you have less control over the relations and primary/foreign keys are done with system created columns. I like to create the tables and data model manually in the relational manner, and then if I need OOP access and programming, I will create an object view on top of my relational tables.

Comment: By the way you can also write like this in sql*plus:
`select t.person.id from t`

Comment: @0bj3ct thank you for your comment, it is really interesting.